# Merge values of objects with ImmutableJS

Tags: immutability, immutable.js

I have a List of several objects.  All with the same keys.  I'm trying to find an efficient way to reduce the values into a single object.

```
var list = Immutable.fromJS([{
  first: 3,
  second: 4,
  third: 2
 }, {
  first: 7,
  second, 6,
  third: 8
 }]);
```

Wanting to return:

```
{first: 10,
 second: 10,
 third: 10}
```

I'm really just trying to find a way to merge an object, but add the values instead of replacing them.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do both objects have the same properties or can one have properties that don't exist on the other?

Comment: They both have the same properties...   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

take the outer array as List and while running reduce, merge inner Maps

```
list.reduce(function(a, b){ 
  return a.
    mergeWith(function(x, y){ 
      return x + y;
    }, b)
}).toJS()
```

Comment: Thanks @webserver, this looks a lot better than the solution i came up with.  Will try it tonight...